# Editing TiddlyWiki files on Android

Tags: owncloud

I just started using [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/), I appreciate very much its technology agnostic paradigm and am convinced it is the right tool to manage my notes. I need to access my notes from both my computer (Linux) and my phone (Android).

I have successfully created Wiki files with Firefox and TiddlyDesktop on my computer, that are being automatically synchronised to a ownCloud server. On my phone the ownCloud client synchronises these files correctly and I am able to open them with the browser. However, I am unable to edit the TiddlyWiki files with either Firefox or Chrome on the phone (none of the buttons functions).

How can I edit on Android these TiddlyWiki files synchronised from ownCloud?

Comment: There's an app named [AndTidWiki](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mgsimon.android.andtidwiki) claiming compatibility, but it hasn't been updated for 5 years.

Comment: @Izzy AndTidWiki is only able to edit files in a specific folder, it can not be used with synchronised assets.

Comment: Ouch. Didn't know that, sorry. Neither I'm familiar with what specific formatting Tiddly uses; maybe one of the other [wiki editors](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_106) could help? In conjunction with ownCloud, I myself use *Markor* (a Markdown editor you find on the linked page). You can specify the folder it shall work in (e.g. on the SD card) and chose one you can sync. But it's not TiddlyWiki format. If you'd be willing to switch to Markdown (use e.g. ReText on your Linux PC), that'd be a solution.

Comment: @Izzy A TiddlyWiki is a just an HTML file (including a good deal of JS and CSS). I believe the issue is with the HTML5 code it has - that Android browsers fail to interpret. I installed Markor yesterday and so far am quite satisfied (it allows the user to select the notes folder). On my computer I can edit the MarkDown notes with any editor like GEdit. I think I will stick to MarkDown, as it is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tiddloid](https://github.com/donmor/Tiddloid), an app to work with locally stored TiddlyWikis, both local file and webdav are supported.

Or use Termux and start a Node.js server on it, but I personally recommend using Tiddloid, it works well.